# How to customize css for the group-label and group-values in vuejs multiselect optionGroup?

Tags: vue-multiselect

I am working with optionGroup in vuejs multiselect. I am trying to make the group-label **bold** and group-value with **padding-left**, and also change the background color of group-label to a bit darker. But all the css i am trying to use is not working. Any help please. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try without using `scoped` in style since vue-multiselect is globally defined css and ` won't work on it.

```
<style>
.multiselect__option--group
{
 background:red !important;
 color:#35495e !important;
 font-weight: bold !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style scoped>
.multiselect__option--group
{
  background:red !important;
  color:#35495e !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
</style>
```

this is what i tried finally